# Can't use fontspec with xelatex after tlmgr update

Tags: xetex, fontspec, mactex

I updated my MacTeX 2011 installation yesterday. Now, compiling the following with xelatex fails:

```
\documentclass[xetex]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
! I can't find file `t3enc.def'.
```

Removing the fontspec line makes it compile OK. How can I get this working again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my system (miktex) t3enc is in the tipa folder: `\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def`. So probably you should install the tipa package.

Comment: That's it. `xunicode` now requires `t3enc.def` for `tipa` compatible. But I think it is better only to load `t3enc.def` when it exists.